# Magento 2.2 - Put a Website under maintanence

Tags: magento2.2, maintenance

I would like to have **multiple website** in my Magento Server. But I need to put only one website under **maintanence** not the entire server.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-maint.html

The commands in the above link is turning the **entire server** to maintanence mode. But, I need to turn only a particular website to Maintanence mode and also I should access the REST API's during the maintanence period.

Answer (score 0):

I know 2 ways of doing:

1st and easiest, simple create a page you want to display, name it as index.php and replace your file on public_html

2nd, go to your index.php file, and add this code on line 49:

```
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
$maintenanceFile = 'maintenance.flag';
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$allowed = array('69.65.23.100','2.2.2.2'); //insert your allowed IP here

if (!file_exists($mageFilename)) {
    if (is_dir('downloader')) {
        header("Location: downloader");
    } else {
        echo $mageFilename." was not found";
    }
    exit;
}

if (file_exists($maintenanceFile) && !in_array($ip, $allowed)) {
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/errors/503.php';
    exit;
}
```

Remember to always have the backup updated.